# How to put a raw query in sequilize model in one non mapped field

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have this in my sportcenter's model:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Sportcenter = sequelize.define('Sportcenter', {
        id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(500),
            allowNull: true,
        },
        counter: {
            type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        },
       ...
```

The fields id and name are in database table, but counter is not. I want to relate "counter" with the raw query (e.a. "select count(id) from sportcenter") and then see it in the json output in the api:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jose",
    "counter": 26,
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Pedro",
    "counter": 26,
},
...
```

how can i get that?

Comment: You can try to use default scopes and add `attrubutes: { include: [<>your attribute]}` there

Comment: Thanks Anatoly, the answer I was looking for was just below in the official doc: using subqueries. I post the answer in case it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using subqueries in my sportcenter service, like this:

```
return this.getAll({
     ...query,
     attributes: [
         'id',
         'name',
         [
             Sequelize.literal(`(
             SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM sportcenter
             )`),
             'counter',
         ],
```

-- or using a variable:

```
const qry = 'select count(*) from sportcenter';
return this.getAll({
    ...query,
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'name',
        [
            Sequelize.literal(`(${qry})`), 'counter',
        ],
```

In the model is not necessary to include 'counter' field:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Sportcenter = sequelize.define('Sportcenter', {
        id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(500),
            allowNull: true,
        },
        // counter: {
        //     type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        // },
       ...
```